# das or was: Relativpronomen

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

In the sentence:

> *Die Room Tour ist das häufigst angefragte Video, **das** / **was** ich je gehabt
> habe.*

what will be the correct pronoun to use? Or both are possible?

I found [this rule](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-wer-was.html#Anchor-wer-14210) but it's still not clear if I should use ***was*** because

> Das Relativpronomen *was* steht in der Regel: nach einem sächlichen substantivierten Superlativ:
> *Das ist das Schönste, **was** ich je gesehen habe.*

or ***das*** because

> Nach sächlichen Nomen muss *das* stehen:
> *das Buch, **das** ich gelesen habe*    NICHT:  *das Buch, was ich gelesen habe*

The latter seems more plausible to me because we have "*das <...> Video, das...*" and *häufigst* is not substantivated.

<sub>I have to tell you the secret: the speaker to whom belongs the original sentence, said "*das häufigst angefragte Video, **was***...". So I'm confused.</sub>

Comment: Aside from the official rules regarding das/was (of which I am not entirely sure myself), I'd like to mention that using *was* is rather common in colloquial use, so the speaker you cite might just have used it in that way.

Comment: @Vogel612 "das ich je hatte" is not Plusqamperfekt. It's Präteritum. Plusqamperfekt will be "das ich je gehabt hatte".

Comment: @stillenat shoops... dammit i hate tempora.

Comment: You answered the question pretty much yourself. It's amazing how a mere native speakdr could not easily extract the rule, and thus understandable if not everyone renders it correctly. However, a quick comparison to English shows that *what* is not usually used as determiner (*this is the most popular video, that ...*).

Comment: Also, this (the superlativ example) is a case where some speakers might use *wo*, just so you know.(crossref. "Im Moment, wo ...", not superlativ though). Not to mention embedded questions, in which case *welches* may replace *das*.

Comment: Wait a second, I do say *das schönste, das ich ...*. The only reason not to do so would be if it clashes with *dass*, but it does not thanks to prosody. I consider *dass* an abomination anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=81) (scroll down to the end) you

1. use the pronoun "was" if it refers to a neuter indefinite- or demonstrative-pronoun in the main clause,
2. can use the pronoun "was" if it refers to a nominalized superlative in the main clause,
3. and use the pronoun "was" if it refers to the whole main clause.

So in your case according to the grammatics it should be

> Die Room-Tour ist das am häufigsten angefragte Video, das ich je hatte.

since the relative pronoun refers to "Video" which is no superlative. But maybe the superlative "am häufigsten" has in this case misguided the speaker to using "was" instead of "das".