# Word Order with Relative Clause and Compound Verbs

Tags: word-order, compound, subordinate-clause

I am looking to translate the sentence

> I'm trying to say in German all the things I would normally say in English.

I am only just beginning to get a grasp on subordinate clauses and the accompanying word order, so my best attempt is

> Ich versuche auf Deutsch alle die Zeuge die ich normalerweise auf Englisch sagen
>   würde sagen.

Any explanation of errors (or poor word choices) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction requires the *zu Infinitiv*.

> Ich versuche X zu tun.

I try to do X.

Zeug does not need the Plural, *all dein Zeug* translates to all your things/stuff. But here, Zeug is the wrong word choice, because it refers to physical stuff. *Sachen* or *Dinge* would be the correct translation.

We can now put this together without the relative clause.

> Ich versuche all die Sachen auf Deutsch zu sagen.

Now we just need to add the relative clause. You already did a good job there.

> Ich versuche all die Dinge, die ich normalerweise auf Englisch sagen würde, auf Deutsch zu sagen.

We can still polish this a little.

> Ich versuche alles, was ich normalerweise auf Englisch sagen würde, auf Deutsch auszudrücken.

Note that for verbs with certain prefixes: auf, ab, zu, unter,... the zu Infinitiv moves in between.

Comment: *Das Zeug/Zeugs* is a mandatory singular noun. There is no plural. It always refers to a collection of things.

Comment: Duden does list a plural form. I couldn't think of an example either, though.

Comment: Wo? https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zeugs#grammatik

Comment: The plural of *das Zeug* is only used in compound words as *das Werkzeug* or *das Fahrzeug*.

Comment: @Janka I thought of "Flugzeuge" and just assumed "Zeuge" existed haha. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @infinitezero Thanks so much for your answer!! Could I ask you to point me to someplace that explains the use of was vs. der/die/das as a subordinating conjunction? I tried and failed to find some explanation. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hier?  https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zeug

Comment: @flevinBombastus this was answered in another post on this site: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/das-or-was-relativpronomen

Comment: I think the question was about the correct gender/number/case of the relative pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question was about the correct gender/number/case of the relative pronoun.

This is tricky! Consider

> Ich helfe einem Frager, **der** Hilfe braucht.
>
> Ich helfe einem Frager, **dessen** Frage ich beantworten kann.
>
> Ich helfe einem Frager, **dem** ich schon einmal geholfen habe.
>
> Ich helfe einem Frager, **den** ich kenne.

These are all valid, though they are all relative to **einem Frager**. You have to understand *der/die/das etc.* is **a pronoun** here. It replaces the noun in question in the additional relation (hence *relative pronoun*) presented in the subordinate clause. Let's put it as main clauses instead.

> Ich helfe einem Frager. **Der** Frager braucht Hilfe
>
> Ich helfe einem Frager. Ich kann **dessen** Frage beantworten.
>
> Ich helfe einem Frager. Ich habe **dem** Frager schon einmal geholfen.
>
> Ich helfe einem Frager. Ich kenne **den** Frager.

In those main clauses, it becomes clear why that gender/number/case was chosen.